How to disable the dark theme in QT Designer
I recently changed the Windows design to dark colors. Now, when running QT Designer, it has a dark theme (before it was light), but this is a dark theme with display artifacts. Question: How do I get the light theme back?
Important: I inserted QT designer in a bundle with PyQt 6 and the QT Creator application
In Windows settings, I tried changing the default application theme setting to light, it didn't help

you can go to 

Edit (left upper corner of the screen)
Preferences (lowest option)
Environemt (3th option in new pop up window)
In the environment settings go to interface (first one)
Then you can select a theme

I don't know for sure what you mean by this part:

I inserted QT designer in a bundle with PyQt 6 and the QT Creator application.

But i hope this helps!
